# Архитектура много-пользовательского клиент-сервера C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

Доброго времени суток друзья, я в поисках решения несколько недель.

Вопрос мой таков:
У меня есть Клиент на Qt с БД (Sqlite)
Имееться возможность регистрации и входа, все базовые вещи.

Я хочу реализовать сервер для этого клиента - QTcpServer, QTcpSocket

Я знаю что мы можем читать и передавать блоки информации между клиентом и сервером, такая реализация мне понятна, в таком случае мы просто можем вывести текст в TextBrowser и посмотреть на это.

Мне нужно что бы я мог найти другого пользователя из БД по логину и смог именно ему написать а не в общий чат. я не совсем понимаю как мне идентифицировать это и реализовать, то ли делать каждый отдельный поток и в него передавать поисковое значение то ли иными способами.

Основная суть вопроса: Как я могу реализовать,и построить архитектуру что бы каждый пользователь смог писать другому пользователю которые есть в БД

C++ 17, Qt 5.15